# Wordpress custom post-type pagination with wp-pagenavi

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called criticos and I'm having problems with pagination.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'post_type' => 'avaliacoes',
    'paged' => $paged,
    //'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    //'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'critico', // name of custom field
        'value' => '"' . $Dados['id'] . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    ));

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    foreach ($loop->posts as $avaliacao) {
   //Do Stuff Here
    }
}
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop  ) );
wp_reset_postdata();
```

The pagination is not working when go to the page 2 redirect to first page.

My page is single-criticos

PS: English isn't my first language.

Comment: Where is the loop (archive, single, index)?

Comment: The loop is on single-criticos.

Comment: There are other loops in single-criticos.php?

Comment: Only this, my url is www.mysite.com.br/criticos/... and my custom post-type is criticos and the slug is also criticos,Is this wrong ?

Comment: If your cpt is `'criticos'` why do you use `'post_type' => 'avaliacoes'` in the WP_Query args?

Comment: I have a custom field 'critico' on cpt avaliacoes and  I get the avaliacoes by this critico by the id.

Comment: I didn't understand very well the hierarchical structure of your site, but if the cpt is `avaliacoes` then the template should also be `single-avaliacoes.php`. Could you post the function for creating the cpt?